# Continuous series of inorganic hydrates (from mono- to deca-)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

I'm doing some research for university and it has to do with crystals. I'm currently experimenting with $\ce{CuSO4 * 5 H2O}$. I know we refer to the formula as copper sulfate pentahydrate. And also, I'm experimenting with $\ce{ZnSO4 * H2O}$ which is a monohydrate.

What chemical compound can be bought with all the 'versions' of the hydrates? I would like to purchase copper sulfate monohydrate, dihydrate, trihydrate, tetrahydrate, pentahydrate, hexahydrate, heptahydrate, octahydrate, nonahydrate, and decahydrate, but I can't find them all (only pentahydrate which I have bought).

Same with $\ce{ZnSO4}$, I have the monohydrate, but I would still like to purchase all the hydrates for my project. I'm a newbie at chemistry. Please, can anyone explain whether there a chemical compound such as the ones above, which can be bought with all the version of the hydrates?

Comment: MgSO4 comes pretty close (though not quite there).

Comment: Iron(II) sulfate is a good candidate too.

Comment: I think that a colossally strong acid such as $\ce{HSbF6}$ will form a series of well-defined hydrates as the naked proton desperately tries to solvate itself with what it can, but you probably don't want to play around with it...